# Nestjs create Generic CRUD service

Tags: typescript, generics, nestjs, typeorm

I want to create a base service using a generic class which I wrote below:

```js
import { BaseEntity } from './base.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

export class BaseService<Entity extends BaseEntity> {
  constructor(private entitiesRepository: Repository<Entity>) {}

  findById(id: number): Promise<Entity> {
    return this.entitiesRepository.findOneBy({ id });
  }
}
```

When I try it, I get the following error:

```
Argument of type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindOptionsWhere<Entity> | FindOptionsWhere<Entity>[]'.
Types of property 'id' are incompatible.     
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhereProperty<NonNullable<Entity["id"]>>'
```

This is my base entity class:

```js
// base.entity.ts
import {
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  CreateDateColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

export class BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isDeleted: boolean;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

None of the above answers fixed the issue. I found an [open issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/8939) on TypeORM GitHub relating to this problem.

For now, I fixed this with `any` type. I know it is not perfect but, it is working for now. I'm looking forward to any other solutions.

```js
import { BaseEntity } from './base.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

export class BaseService<Entity extends BaseEntity> {
  constructor(private entitiesRepository: Repository<Entity>) {}

  findById(id: any): Promise<Entity> {
    return this.entitiesRepository.findOneBy({ id });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decorate your BaseEntity class @Entity() as stated in the documentation :
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#repository-pattern

```js
// base.entity.ts
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  CreateDateColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isDeleted: boolean;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried with the string type? What is the SQL definition of your ID column? I will test on my computer then

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert here, but I think typescript is complaining that BaseEntity doesn't extend ObjectLiteral:

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/repository/Repository.ts#L22
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/common/ObjectLiteral.ts

I think all you need to do is add "extends ObjectLiteral" and the corresponding import to BaseEntity.

Like:

```
import { ObjectLiteral } from 'typeorm';
```

And then:

```
export class BaseEntity extends ObjectLiteral {
```

Comment: First of all, you must implement the ObjectLiteral interface instead of extending it.
But, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @ParsaGhadimkhani ah sorry, i always get extends and implements backwards

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using an outdated version of typeorm. findOneBy is deprecated and removed in the recent releases.

Update typeorm and try this:

```js
findById(id: number): Promise<Entity> {
    return this.entitiesRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

Comment: No, I am using the latest version of typeorm 0.3.6

Comment: the deprecated function is findOneById.